# Angular custom directive: evaluate attribute to decide which templateUrl to use

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make a custom directive to be used inside an ng-repeat. The idea is that I have a list of books I want to display, and the books have different types. I want to load a separate template depending on the type of the book (`horrorTemplate.html` for horror books, `scifiTemplate.html` for sci-fi books etc). I'm also going to be setting some scope variables later on depending on the type of the book, but I want to get the correct template loaded first. What I currently have is the following:

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('group', function() {
    return {
        scope: false,
        templateUrl: function(elem, attr) {
            switch (attr.template) {
                case 'horror':
                    return 'horrorTemplate.html';
                    break;
                case 'scifi':
                    return 'scifiTemplate.html';
                    break;
                default:
                    return 'defaultTemplate.html';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Template:**

```
<div ng-repeat="book in books">
    <book template="{{book.type}}"></book>
</div>
```

At the moment, the directive is always loading `defaultTemplate.html`. I've gone through lots of stackoverflow answers already, but none of them seem to address the exact issue I'm having.

Comment: See the answer linked by the "possible duplicate" comment above (and feel free to upvote the answer there :)), but to summarize: `attr.template` is not yet interpolated when `templateUrl` runs, and so its value is a string `"{{book.type}}"`.

Comment: Seems to work fine, apart from some CSS issues I have to fix due to the use of `ng-include` and div nesting or something. Thanks! :) EDIT: CSS issues also fixed, hooray! You're awesome <3